# jq touch id attar occurring twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, jqtouch

```
 $('#news_details').bind('pageAnimationEnd', function (e, info) {
          // get the id of the calling href
          //alert('we are here');
          var id = $(this).data('referrer')[0].id;
          //alert(id);
          $.get('http://localhost/school_app/admin/json/news_pagination.php?id=' + id, function (data) {
            // do something with the data
            //alert(data);
              $('#detail_news').append(data);
            //alert('we are here');
          });
        });
```

I am getting this id and passing it to the `#news_details` page, it is successfully but when I like the page the script occurs automatically by itself, and when I go to the `#new_detail` page with another id var the previous data is still there.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#news_details').bind('pageAnimationEnd', function (e, info) {
          // get the id of the calling href
          //alert('we are here');
          var id = $(this).data('referrer')[0].id;
          //alert(id);
          $.get('http://localhost/school_app/admin/json/news_pagination.php?id=' + id, function (data) {
            // do something with the data
            //alert(data);
              $('#detail_news').html(data);
            //alert('we are here');
          });
        });
```

Instead of using $('#detail_news').append(data);

use $('#detail_news').html(data);

it would work....